# URL redirect and weird domain name which works

Tags: domain, redirection, url

So there is an URL like example.example.com which when I visit it redirects to `10.10.0.5/folder/index.pl` How does that work? I thought redirects work to only non-private IPs.

Also, my TeamSpeak Server I use contains only three letters like `xyz` and is so no real TLD (because it contains no dot) and I can connect to the server using this string. How does that work? Does TeamSpeak use some kind of special name resolution?

If I posted this at the wrong StackExchange site please migrate my question.

Comment: Why the downvote?..

Comment: Please read the Help section. I would guess one reason for the close votes is that we ask that each question have only a SINGLE question so that a single answer can be sufficient. You have two questions in here.

Answer (score 1):

> I thought redirects work to only non-private IPs.

No, there is no such limitation.

There are several ways this redirect might be implemented. [This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#Implementation) sums them up very well.

Comment: And any idea on the second part of the question?

Comment: ```xyz``` is a valid (local) domain name, like ```localhost``` is. There is no need for a ```.``` to make a domain name valid.

Comment: And how do you register such a domain name?

Comment: You can not. But you can define it inside your ```hosts``` file, or set up your own DNS server for your LAN.

Comment: but I did not set anything up in hosts file, how does that work then?

Comment: Programs may potentially modify `hosts`. Otherwise, yes, there could theoretically be some kind of "special" resolution regarding the names (done by TeamSpeak).